# Storing multiple values for keys?

Tags: java, hashmap

In Python, a dictionary can contain a key and many values for that key. I've been trying to look at Java, but there is no simple way of doing this without trying to use something like `HashMap<String, List>` I read that this way is very bad and it's called `chaining` and that it will cause a performance issue. I need to store more than hundreds of millions of keys so I need something that can scale. Each day this hash map will be emptied.

My HashMap needs to have 4 values per key like so: country, volume, network, and date. A fake example of a key looks like this: "EJTER" would it be efficient and feasible if I did something like this "EJTER_country", "EJTER_volume", "EJTER_network", "EJTER_date". These will be the keys and each respective key will have its own value. The only downside to this I see is that there will be 4x more keys than normal.

Comment: You have to store hundreds of millions of keys *in memory*?!

Comment: @azurefrog Sounds crazy, but this is a quick proof of concept we are creating

Comment: Sounds like you want to have a class with fields called `country`, `volume`, `network` and `date`.

Comment: Have you thought of using SQL to store these? I'm curious to see if you can store these in memory without speed problems.

Comment: General principle: things in Java often use up more memory than you initially expect them to.  Unless you're running this on a server with an absolute ton of RAM, you might want to consider a different design.  Like maybe use a database, for example.

Comment: @DawoodsaysreinstateMonica We are running this on a server. This is just a quick proof of concept design that won't look like this in the future. Also, how would that be implemented with a class having those fields? How would the hashmap be implemented?

Comment: With strings as the keys, and objects of your new class as values.

Comment: @DawoodsaysreinstateMonica Do you think that is performant though? It sounds like it would be a bit slow

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: @DawoodsaysreinstateMonica arent we creating millions of objects? Doesnt that put a lot of stress on memory?

Comment: Well, yes.  You said there are hundreds of millions of keys.  I don't understand your point.  In Java, everything in memory is either objects or primitives - and it doesn't look like you're going to be storing a whole lot of primitives.

Comment: @DawoodsaysreinstateMonica just wondering, how does my idea of adding the type of value we are storing in the key compare to your solution? I know your solution is much more scalable, but which do you think is more efficient?

Comment: Mine. :-) :-) :-)

Comment: *I read that this way is very bad and it's called chaining and that it will cause a performance issue.*  Where did you read this?  Seems to me any signficant performance hit would depend on how the `List` is implemented.

Comment: @DawoodsaysreinstateMonica I see, thank you so much for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at Guava [MultiMap](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html), it seems to be what you are looking for.